# Keypad remember last pressed number VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, keypad, seven-segment-display

First of all sorry for my bad English, hope you understand my problem

I have an project "time bomb". I work with a keypad and Nexys 3 FPGA. 
I have to click two numbers for example 1 and 2 and confirm by definied number or letter on keypad. Then it have to display on 7 segment display and start to count down to 0. 12,11,10,9... 0. I don't have a problem to click a digit (0-9) and display it, but the problem is when I want to display two digits (10-99). I press 1 and ok it's display on two 7 segment displays. Then I press 2 and display on two segment display but i only wanted to display on one. So I have result 22 but I wanted to see 21 or 12 it depends on the convention which we assume.
The two commented process was our try to do this but didn't work.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity mojaklaw is
    Port (SEG : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);  -- segmenty wyświetlacza 
                         DP : out std_logic; -- kropki na wyswietlaczu
                         ENABLE : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); -- anody wyswietlacza
                         CLK : in std_logic; -- zegar
                         ROW : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); -- rzad klawiatury
                         COL : buffer std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); -- kolumna klawiatury
                         LEDS : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) ); -- diody led

end mojaklaw;

architecture Behavioral of mojaklaw is
signal Q : std_logic_vector(22 downto 0); -- 4-bitowy licznik sterujacy
signal KeyCode : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); -- kod przycisku klawiatury
signal KeyCode1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); -- kod przycisku klawiatury 2
signal DIGIT : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); -- konwersja kodu klawiatury
signal En : std_logic; -- '0' oznacza wcisniety przycisk klawiatury




begin
DP<='1'; -- wygaszenie kropek (dots turn off)


process(CLK) begin -- 4-bit COUNTER
if rising_edge(CLK) then
if En='1' then Q<=Q+1; end if;
end if;
end process;


with Q(20 downto 19) select -- MUX
En<= ROW(0) when "00", ROW(1) when "01", ROW(2) when "10", ROW(3) when "11", '1' when others;
with Q(22 downto 21) select -- DECODER
COL<= "1110" when "00", "1101" when "01", "1011" when "10", "0111" when "11", "1111" when others;


--process(CLK) begin -- REGISTER
--if rising_edge(CLK) then
--if En='0' then KeyCode<=Q(22 downto 19); Q2<='1'; end if;
--if Q2='1' then if En='0' then KeyCode1<=KeyCode; end if;
--else KeyCode1<="1111"; end if;
--end if;
----end process;

--process (CLK) 
-- variable Q2 : integer;
--begin
--if rising_edge(CLK) then
--if Q2=1 then
--if En='0' then KeyCode1<=KeyCode; Q2:=0; end if;
--else 
--if En='0' then KeyCode<=Q(22 downto 19); Q2:=1; end if;
--end if; -- if Q2
--end if; -- if edge
--end process;

process(CLK) begin -- REGISTER keycode
if rising_edge(CLK) then
if En='0' then KeyCode<=Q(22 downto 19); 
end if; end if;
end process;



-- MUX 7SEGMENT LCD
with Q(17 downto 16) select 
DIGIT <= KeyCode when "00", KeyCode1 when "01", "1111" when "10", "1111" when others;


-- CONVERTER 7SEGMENT LCD konwersja kodu klawiatury na wyswietlacz 7segmentowy
process(DIGIT) begin
case DIGIT is
when "0011" => SEG <= "0000001"; -- 0
when "0000" => SEG <= "1001111"; -- 1
when "0100" => SEG <= "0010010"; -- 2
when "1000" => SEG <= "0000110"; -- 3
when "0001" => SEG <= "1001100"; -- 4
when "0101" => SEG <= "0100100"; -- 5
when "1001" => SEG <= "0100000"; -- 6
when "0010" => SEG <= "0001111"; -- 7
when "0110" => SEG <= "0000000"; -- 8
when "1010" => SEG <= "0000100"; -- 9
when others => SEG <= "1111111"; -- -
end case;
end process;

-- DECODER 7SEGMENT LCD
with Q(17 downto 16) select
ENABLE <= "1110" when "00", "1101" when "01",
"1011" when "10", "0111" when others ;


end Behavioral;
```

AND HERE IS OUR PIN ALLOCATION:

```
NET "CLK" LOC="V10"; # CLK

NET "COL(3)" LOC="H3"; # JC1
NET "COL(2)" LOC="L7"; # JC2
NET "COL(1)" LOC="K6"; # JC3
NET "COL(0)" LOC="G3"; # JC4
NET "ROW(3)" LOC="G1"; # JC7
NET "ROW(2)" LOC="J7"; # JC8
NET "ROW(1)" LOC="J6"; # JC9
NET "ROW(0)" LOC="F2"; # JC10


NET "SEG(6)" LOC="T17"; # A
NET "SEG(5)" LOC="T18"; # B
NET "SEG(4)" LOC="U17"; # C
NET "SEG(3)" LOC="U18"; # D
NET "SEG(2)" LOC="M14"; # E
NET "SEG(1)" LOC="N14"; # F
NET "SEG(0)" LOC="L14"; # G
NET "DP" LOC="M13"; #DP

NET "ENABLE(3)" LOC="P17"; #AN3
NET "ENABLE(2)" LOC="P18"; #AN2
NET "ENABLE(1)" LOC="N15"; #AN1
NET "ENABLE(0)" LOC="N16"; #AN0



NET "LEDS(3)" LOC="V15"; # LD3
NET "LEDS(2)" LOC="U15"; # LD2
NET "LEDS(1)" LOC="V16"; # LD1
NET "LEDS(0)" LOC="U16"; # LD0
```

Comment: I think you should be filtering glitches on your input signal. The reason you are having 22 instead of 12 is the glitches cause you to have mutliple inputs of 2.  You can do it by adding a little time delay after receiving your keycode input.

Comment: Indeed, what Alper says. Put at least a 2-stage synchronizer on your external inputs. Glitches can lock-up internal state machines, so synchronization is very important.